# Liquibase scripts not being executed in Spring boot multi module project fat jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

I've got a multi module Spring boot application which I've integrated with Liquibase. When running it from an IDE, the liquibase scripts work just fine. However, when running it from a jar, they don't. After some investigation, it seems that liquibase itself has major problems when trying to read from embedded jars. The liquibase scripts themselves are present in embedded jars inside the fat jar, and the master xml file looks like this:

```
<includeAll path="classpath*:config/liquibase/changelog/"/>
```

After further investigation I narrowed everything down to a problem inside liquibase itself. The version I'm using is liquibase-3.6.2. The bug I suspect to be present in liquibase is in the following class:
liquibase.resource.ClassLoaderResourceAccessor
The method I narrowed it down to is

```
public Set<String> list(String relativeTo, String path, boolean includeFiles, boolean includeDirectories, boolean recursive) throws IOException
```

The input for this method is the following:

```
relativeTo = null
path = jar:file:/C:/#{SOME_PATH}/xxx-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/yyy-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/config/liquibase/changelog/
includeFiles = true
includeDirectories = false
recursive = true
```

Of course, you will need to replace #{SOME_PATH} with a valid path on the disk. I edited it out for security purposes. We can already notice that liquibase figured out that there may be some scripts inside an embedded yyy jar inside the fat jar xxx.

The problem with this method is that instead of returning the XML scripts inside the jar, it returns the yyy jar itself. This will simply cause an error later in the code, so I have assumed that it's this method's responsibility to find the XML files (as it does so successfully if I run my project  directly from an IDE and not from a jar).

The line which I've noticed major problems in is at line 134:

```
String returnPath = SpringBootFatJar.getSimplePathForResources(entry.getName(), path);
```

At this point, the path variable is broken and the SpringBootFatJar returns a broken return path. In the following part I will describe what happens:

- At line 105, the path variable is split and becomes "config/liquibase/changelog/". Based on how it's used at line 134 and the javadoc inside the SpringBootFatJar class, this could be very bad.
- Fast forward to line 134, entry.getName() returns "BOOT-INF/lib/yyy-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" and path is the same as above. Based on the javadoc inside SpringBootFatJar, this is very bad.
- After line 134, returnPath becomes "BOOT-INF/lib/yyy-1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" and the rest is history, as the nestedEntries at line 143 will never start with that path.

Unfortunately I don't have the time to investigate this further this week and I wanted to post this question on stackoverflow in order to see whether anybody else has this issue, whether it's a known liquibase bug and whether there's an easy fix for it. I will try to investigate it further myself next week, and check whether all these issues cascade from the seemingly poorly split path parameter at line 105, as the inputted path parameter has TWO "!/" instances inside of it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

apparently it's still not working with the current liquibase version (3.8.5). Changelogs are not picked up from other jars in a spring boot fat jar.
A workaround could be to overwrite the SpringLiquibase.java file and update the jar list manually. Details on this can be found here: http://www.it-surmann.com/spring-boot/fix-liquibase-includeall-in-a-spring-boot-project_1002.html

Comment: Update December 2020
The Liquibase PR 1140 has been merged into 3.10.x branch. Starting with 2.3.7, the new version is also integrated into Spring Boot - everything should now work as expected!

If you would like to initialize a Spring Boot project with custom database schema, multi-module option and Liquibase scripts, check out Bootify.io - create your first prototype in no time.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else  stumbles upon this question, they fixed it on master but there's no release yet. What we did is took their master from github and compiled a SNAPSHOT from that. The result as of writing this comment is 3.7.0-SNAPSHOT. We will use the official 3.7.0 release when they get to it.